# Why am I getting this error when opening my website in WebMatrix from website folder?

Tags: php, asp.net, wordpress

I am getting this error when directly opening through my website folder:

[image]

I am getting this second error when I try to open through Open->folder option. this error directly stops and closes WebMatrix:

[image]

Comment: this is regarding wordpress????

Comment: The website he's trying to open is a wordpress website @VasimVanzara

Comment: @Kevin.a This is OS related issue.

Comment: I think if you open the same url it will be open without any error.

Comment: this is related to wordpress

Comment: i have tried many time but its not working

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1 : NeemusOfficial**

There is .exe missing or corrupt. you can ask to software support center for this issue.

**Problem 2 :  WebMatrix**

WebMatrix.Data.dll is a type of DLL file associated with MSDN Disc 5095 developed by Microsoft for the Windows Operating System.You have to download from a Microsoft official site (Recommended).

This is system issue not website issue.Please open same url in some other machine for better understanding.If you would like to share url please add url here.I hop this will be clear now.

Comment: I will try it .

Comment: i have installed webmatrix from web platform installer

Comment: Please first run system or registry fixer tool